# How would a Flash based sound recorder/player application object communicate with JavaScript within a web page?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, dom-events

I need to communicate to a Flash Developer to build a Flash recorder that can record audio from the browser. In addition to all the things that the Flash recorder needs to do it also needs to be able to:

- In the event that the user declines access to their microphone or their microphone can't be accessed to trigger a JavaScript based modal window to pop up with a message to let the user know that they can go any further without access to their microphone
- In the event that user records sound and they finish recording by pressing the stop button that a hidden html input field gets populated with the length of the recording in seconds.

So what would be the best way of doing this? I'm not sure how to best communicate this with the Flash Developer in a spec.

Do I define JavaScript custom events that the player needs to trigger when any of the two above events occur ?

I'm very partial to using jQuery by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ExternalInterface](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/external-interface/) to establish communication/callbacks between actionscript and javascript.

I recommend using SWFObject as it also handles  and id/name issues that could break communication in some browsers.

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = { id: "ExternalInterfaceExample", name: "ExternalInterfaceExample" };

swfobject.embedSWF("ExternalInterfaceExample.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "200", "8", "/path/to/expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

function sendToFlash(text) {
  var swf = document.getElementById("ExternalInterfaceExample");
  swf.sendTextToFlash(text);
}
```

The example is from the linked site, notice how the id and name are the same. Check out the [demo](http://demos.learnswfobject.com/external-interface/dynamic.html)

Comment: No worries. Your flash developer should be familiar with the [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)...it's easy to pick up if he/she isn't. Making sure communication works across browser is generally the issue, but that's where swfobject comes in :)